# meaning of "beauty handicaps"

Tags: word-usage

The sententence is from an article about "Looking Good".

> People with all kinds of *beauty handicaps* have
>    easy, loving relationships.

I am so confused with the meaning of "beauty handicaps".
Does it mean *being ugly*  or *being disabled*?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The statement might also refer to unwelcome facial features that are difficult to disguise with make-up - features such as scars and pimples.

Answer (score 1):

The term for these kind of phrases is [*euphemism*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/euphemism).  This is where you substitute a nice-sounding phrase for one that is impolite or possibly offensive.

In this case, "beauty handicap" is a euphemism for "unattractive".  Other examples of euphemisms:

> Her father *passed* last night (he died)
>
> The ramp is there to provide access for the *physically challenged* (people in wheelchairs or with other handicaps)
>
> We've had to put mother in a *home* (old-age facility)

and many others.

Edit:  In my opinion this is one of the most inept attempts at *euphemism* I've seen -- but a terrible euphemism is still a euphemism.  What matters is that the writers of this article are *trying* to say something nice, even if they're not really very good at it.

Comment: I don't think you can say that *"beauty handicap" is a euphemism for "unattractive"* exactly.  Firstly, they're different parts of speech, but more importantly, I wouldn't say that someone with a "beauty handicap" *is* unattractive, simply that they have some kind of handicap or challenge regarding their beauty, but nothing in this sentence implies that it can't be overcome - in fact, just the opposite, since they have "easy, loving" relationships.

Comment: @stangdon the article seems to be saying that even unattractive people can have loving relationships.  I've no opinion whether this is true or not, only what it *means*.

Comment: I kind of agree with @stangdon here, but for a different reason. I'm not sure that "beauty handicap" sounds all that polite, mild, or pleasant, so I don't think I'd classify it as a true euphemism. It's interesting that [this version](https://github.com/edumyanmar/grade11-english/blob/master/text/unit10.md) of the text puts the expression in scare quotes.

Comment: @J.R. Is a *failed* euphemism still a euphemism?

Comment: Maybe, but for it to qualify in this case, I think you'd have to expand the definition you provide. I don't think this is "a substitution of a nice-sounding phrase for one that is impolite." [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism) has a broader article about euphemisms; you might be able to convince me this is a euphemism if you borrowed from that material. As sifted through it, I noticed that some "failed euphemisms" might be classified successful [dysphemisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysphemism). Interesting question, in any case.

Comment: @J.R. that seems more a question for EL&U.  For simplicity I would just go with the writers apparent *intention* and not the inartful *result*.

Comment: @Andrew I think "beauty handicap" is more of a euphemism for a particular point of unattractiveness.  "I have two beauty handicaps, a big nose and yellow teeth".